# aes_string does not evaluate nested ifelse correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using nested `ifelse` statements to highlight extreme high/low values in a dataset. Rather than adding an extra column for colour aesthetics (I know how to do this), I wanted to try using `aes_string(... , colour = ...)` as this plot will go into a function (hence the `aes_string` instead of `aes`).

Below is a simple example of `ggplot2` evaluating nested `ifelse` statements and incorrectly colouring incorrectly.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
sample <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

# [Plot 1] Works fine using aes and stipulating variables
ggplot(sample, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = ifelse(x < 3, 1, ifelse(x > 7, 10, x)))) +
  scale_colour_identity()

# [Plot 2] "x" replaced by "var" and "aes" replaced by "aes_string"
var = "x"
ggplot(sample, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes_string(colour = ifelse(var < 3, 1, ifelse(var > 7, 10, var)))) +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image: aes() works correctly]

[Plot 1] You can see at the start and end the colours are highlighted blue (1) and red (10) respectively.

[image: aes_string() doesn't work correctly]

[Plot 2] You can see that all the points are highlighted red (10) indicating something has gone wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is not a bug. for `aes_string` the parameter should be quoted explicitly. You can try: `var = "x";
aes_col <- gsub('var', var, 'ifelse(var < 3, 1, ifelse(var > 7, 10, var))');
ggplot(sample, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point(aes_string(colour =  aes_col)) +
    scale_colour_identity()`.

Comment: Or `aes_string(colour = "ifelse(get(var) < 3, 1, ifelse(get(var) > 7, 10, get(var)))")`.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake! An entire string needed to be passed to `colour`, not just the bits and piece I wanted. Thanks @mt1022, that works well. @lukeA, if you put your comment as an answer I'll happily accept it as the solution as it looks a tad more elegant to me